# Tweepy import Error on HDFS running on Centos 7

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, hdfs, tweepy, centos7

I have a Hadoop Cluster running on Centos 7. I am running a program (sitting on HDFS) to extract tweets and I need to import tweepy for that. I did `pip install tweepy` as `root` on all the nodes of the cluster but i still get an import error when I run the program.

Error says: `ImportError: No module named tweepy`

I am sure Tweepy is installed because, `pip freeze | grep "tweepy"` returns `tweepy==3.5.0`.

I created another file `x.py` with just one line `import tweepy` in the `/tmp` folder and that runs without an error. Error occurs only on HDFS.

Also, my default python is Python 2.7.12 which I installed using Anaconda. Can someone help me with this issue? The same code is running without any such errors on another cluster running on Centos 6.6. Is it an OS issue? Or do I have to look into the Cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using Anaconda's Python to run your script, but you installed `tweepy` into CentOS's system installation of Python using `pip`. Either use `conda` to install `tweepy`, or use Anaconda's `pip` executable to install `tweepy` onto your Hadoop cluster.

Comment: Thanks! But `which pip` returns `~/anaconda2/bin/pip
` So I believe I am using the `pip` from anacondato install tweepy. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @kskp you said in your question you ran `pip` as root. Log in as root and run `which pip`, I bet it'll be different.

Comment: Running `which pip` as root returns `/root/anaconda2/bin/pip`. Actually, I installed Anaconda as both Root ans as my user name. Is that creating a porblem? How do I install something as root so that it is available to all users?

Comment: @kskp I'm not terribly familiar with Anaconda, but the installer should give you some sort of option to install globally, instead of in your user directory. One more idea though - how are you running your Python script? Is it executable, and has a shebang as its first line? If so, what is the shebang? Alternatively, can you add the line `import sys; print(sys.version + "\n" + sys.executable)` to the top of your script and report what it prints?